Injected MinHook override not executing
I am trying to override GetSystemTime in order to change the returned time using an injected DLL. I've followed the MinHook documentation and have written this code:
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "MinHook.h" 

typedef void (WINAPI* GETSYSTEMTIME)(LPSYSTEMTIME); 


GETSYSTEMTIME originalGetSystemTime = nullptr;
void WINAPI customGetSystemTime(LPSYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime) {

    originalGetSystemTime(lpSystemTime);

    char buffer[100];
    sprintf_s(buffer, "Current time: %02d:%02d:%02d", lpSystemTime->wHour, lpSystemTime->wMinute, lpSystemTime->wSecond);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, buffer, "Notification", MB_OK);
}

int setupHook() {
    if (MH_Initialize() != MH_OK) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hook initialized", "Notification", MB_OK);
    }

    if (MH_CreateHook(&GetSystemTime, &customGetSystemTime, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&originalGetSystemTime)) != MH_OK) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (MH_EnableHook(&GetSystemTime) != MH_OK) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0; 
}

// DLL entry point
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        setupHook(); 
    }
    return TRUE;
}

Unfortunately, customGetSystemTime never seems to run, I never get the MessageBoxA popup when the function is called. I am getting the Hook initialized so I am injected successfully I believe. I am using Xenos to inject, any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using 64 bit Windows

I think your code (example) misses somethings, like what you do in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH in your dllmain? (Note I do not know much about hooking, but at some point you need to do something there)

@PepijnKramer This is the full Ii have so far, DllMain runs and after the dll attaches, runs the setupHook function. I'm not sure what else I would be missing.

What I would do is search for examples, like googling for "DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH" and "MH_EnableHook". Being able to find documentation/examples is a skill any developer should develop ;). This quickly gives me this : https://github.com/CCob/SylantStrike/blob/master/SylantStrike/dllmain.cpp. An example of someone who did this before and from which I could learn (as said I haven't hooked before, but I do know how to find examples to learn from)

Significant restrictions are imposed on the functions that can be called within DllMain. Certainly to fancy stuff (such as setting up hooks or showing UI) is allowed. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices#general-best-practices @PepijnKramer That example is pretty bad though. The first thing it does is CreateThread call from DllMain which is explicitly prohibited by the docs.
